# Two columns for a pop up sub menu in outlook

Tags: vba, outlook, menu, popup

I have a menu-bar with a sub menu that shows in one column; but I don't know how to make the pop up sub menu in 2 columns with a separator in between .

Here is my code :

```
 Set oCBsubmnuMails = oCBmnuMails.Controls.Add(msoControlPopup, 1, , , True)

 oCBsubmnuMails.Caption = "DT 2"

 oCBsubmnuMails.BeginGroup = True  'separator

Call addButton(oCBsubmnuMails, newBtn, "Mail_standard.buttons.test1", "DT 2.1", Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\" & "icondiedpe.bmp")
Call addButton(oCBsubmnuMails, newBtn, "Mail_standard.buttons.test2", "DT 2.2", Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\" & "icondiedpe.bmp")
Call addButton(oCBsubmnuMails, newBtn, "Mail_standard.buttons.test3", "DT 2.3", Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\" & "icondiedpe.bmp")
Call addButton(oCBsubmnuMails, newBtn, "Mail_standard.buttons.test1", "DT 2.4", Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\" & "icondiedpe.bmp")
Call addButton(oCBsubmnuMails, newBtn, "Mail_standard.buttons.test2", "DT 2.5", Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\" & "icondiedpe.bmp")

Call addButton(oCBsubmnuMails, newBtn, "Mail_standard.buttons.test3", "DT 2.6", Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\" & "icondiedpe.bmp")
Call addButton(oCBsubmnuMails, newBtn, "Mail_standard.buttons.test1", "DT 2.7", Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\" & "icondiedpe.bmp")
Call addButton(oCBsubmnuMails, newBtn, "Mail_standard.buttons.test2", "DT 2.8", Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\" & "icondiedpe.bmp")
Call addButton(oCBsubmnuMails, newBtn, "Mail_standard.buttons.test3", "DT 2.9", Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\" & "icondiedpe.bmp")
Call addButton(oCBsubmnuMails, newBtn, "Mail_standard.buttons.test1", "DT 2.10", Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\" & "icondiedpe.bmp")

Call addButton(oCBsubmnuMails, newBtn, "Mail_standard.buttons.test2", "DT 2.11", Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\" & "icondiedpe.bmp")
Call addButton(oCBsubmnuMails, newBtn, "Mail_standard.buttons.test3", "DT 2.12", Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\" & "icondiedpe.bmp")
Call addButton(oCBsubmnuMails, newBtn, "Mail_standard.buttons.test1", "DT 2.13", Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\" & "icondiedpe.bmp")
Call addButton(oCBsubmnuMails, newBtn, "Mail_standard.buttons.test2", "DT 2.14", Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\" & "icondiedpe.bmp")
Call addButton(oCBsubmnuMails, newBtn, "Mail_standard.buttons.test3", "DT 2.15", Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\" & "icondiedpe.bmp")

Call addButton(oCBsubmnuMails, newBtn, "Mail_standard.buttons.test1", "DT 2.16", Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\" & "icondiedpe.bmp")
Call addButton(oCBsubmnuMails, newBtn, "Mail_standard.buttons.test2", "DT 2.17", Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\" & "icondiedpe.bmp")
Call addButton(oCBsubmnuMails, newBtn, "Mail_standard.buttons.test3", "DT 2.18", Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\" & "icondiedpe.bmp")
Call addButton(oCBsubmnuMails, newBtn, "Mail_standard.buttons.test1", "DT 2.19", Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\" & "icondiedpe.bmp")
Call addButton(oCBsubmnuMails, newBtn, "Mail_standard.buttons.test2", "DT 2.20", Environ("APPDATA") & "\Microsoft\Templates\Document Themes\" & "icondiedpe.bmp")
```